# Cast double to long, weird exception

Tags: java, json, casting

I'm parsing a JSON file with `org.json.simple` and I've got an error that is pissing me off and I can't fix it. Hope you can help me.
The problem is that, with this code appears the following exception `java.lang.Double cannot be cast to java.lang.Long`
The "weird" thing of it is that, if I change the "double variables" to "long variables", the following error appears: `java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.Double`. 
Can you please help me?

```
private double[] tminOWaux = new double[7];
private double[] tmaxOWaux = new double[7];
private double[] humOWaux = new double[7];
private double[] windOWaux = new double[7];
public void filtraOW7days(String contenidoOW) throws ParseException{ 
    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    try{
        Object obj = parser.parse(contenidoOW);
        JSONObject jsonList = (JSONObject) obj;
        JSONArray list = (JSONArray) jsonList.get("list");
        Iterator<String> unitsIterator = list.iterator();
        int i = 0;
        while(unitsIterator.hasNext()){
            Object uJson = unitsIterator.next();
            JSONObject uj = (JSONObject) uJson;
            this.humOWaux[i] =  (double) uj.get("humidity");
            this.windOWaux[i] = (double) uj.get("speed");

            JSONObject slideContent = (JSONObject) uj.get("temp");
            this.tmaxOWaux[i] = (double) slideContent.get("max");
            this.tminOWaux[i] = (double) slideContent.get("min");

            i++;
        }

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

The JSON is:

```
{
"city":{
"id":2643743,
"name":"London",
"coord":{
"lon":-0.12574,
"lat":51.50853
},
"country":"GB",
"population":0
},
"cod":"200",
"message":0.0217,
"cnt":7,
"list":[
{
"dt":1440590400,
"temp":{
"day":18.89,
"min":15.64,
"max":18.89,
"night":15.64,
"eve":18.89,
"morn":18.89
},
"pressure":1008.2,
"humidity":97,
"weather":[ 
{
"id":501,
"main":"Rain",
"description":"moderate rain",
"icon":"10d"
}
],
"speed":4.37,
"deg":229,
"clouds":76,
"rain":5.8
},
]
}
```

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `JSONObject` is actually a `HashMap` that may have values of different types.

Apparently, the 4 calls to `get()` for the array assignments in the `while` loop may return a `Number` object (either a `Long` or a `Double`) and casting among these types is not allowed in `Java`.

So, what is needed is a simple helper function like either of

```
  private static long longValue(Object value) {
    return (value instanceof Number ? ((Number)value).longValue() : -1);
  }

  private static double doubleValue(Object value) {
    return (value instanceof Number ? ((Number)value).doubleValue() : -1.0);
  }
```

where -1 denotes an invalid value (which of course can be anything else). Using `instanceof` should be fast enough and it also covers for `null` values, thus avoiding `NullPointerExceptions`.

If all the array values to be assigned are `long`, then the latter 3 assignments need to call `longValue()`. If all the array values are `double`, using `doubleValue()` for the first assignment should work, i.e.

```
this.humOWaux[i] = doubleValue(uj.get("humidity"));
```

For safety reasons, though, better use the `longValue()` or `doubleValue()` for all assignments, as applicable.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! It worked! Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 1):

I suppose your problem lies in the fact that you can't convert wrappers directly from one type to another. This kind of conversion is only allowed with primitives, as you can see in the [Java SE Specifications, Chapter 5. Conversions and Promotions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html).

I'd try using `Double.longValue()` instead of casting directly.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake while copying the code. I fixed it, I'm casting to double but it says: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.Double

Comment: @catasturslykid apparently, `JSONObject` is not returning what you expect. Try inspecting your code with a debugger to see which type is this.

Comment: @catasturslykid in which part of the code is trhowing the error?

Comment: @melli-182 The error appears on: "his.humOWaux[i] =  (double) uj.get("humidity");"

Comment: @catasturslykid doesn't PNS' answer solve your problem?